# EXTJS Grid inside a tab - filter only works on page refresh

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

we are using extjs 4.1 and i have run into a weird issue. We have a group of 3 tabs and those tabs contains extjs grids. extjs grids in the first 2 are loading the data fine and also have filter option. extjs grid in the 3rd tab, loads the data but does not show the filter menu. However, when the page is refreshed while on the 3rd tab, the grid shows the filter menu. i am new to extjs. please help.

```
ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:144232 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of null
at constructor.showMenuBy (ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:144232)
at constructor.onHeaderTriggerClick (ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:141028)
at constructor.onElClick (ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:142124)
at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at cacheableFunctionFactory (ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:683), <anonymous>:6:13)
at HTMLDivElement.wrap (ext-all-debug-w-comments-v4.1.2a.js:15197)
```

the following line is where the error is happening but this line is within extjs

```
 showMenuBy: function(t, header) {
    var menu = this.getMenu(),
        groupMenuItem  = menu.down('#groupMenuItem'), //this menu is null and therefore the error but this is auto generated by extjs
        groupMenuMeth = header.groupable === false ?  'disable' : 'enable',
        groupToggleMenuItem  = menu.down('#groupToggleMenuItem');

    groupMenuItem[groupMenuMeth](); //this statement is null and throws the error
    if (groupToggleMenuItem) {
        groupToggleMenuItem[this.view.store.isGrouped() ?  'enable' : 'disable']();
    }
    Ext.grid.header.Container.prototype.showMenuBy.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

//code from the onHeaderTrigerClick stackTrace:

```
onHeaderTriggerClick: function(header, e, t) {
    // generate and cache menu, provide ability to cancel/etc
    var me = this;
    if (header.fireEvent('headertriggerclick', me, header, e, t) !== false && me.fireEvent("headertriggerclick", me, header, e, t) !== false) {
        me.showMenuBy(t, header);
    }
}
```

//code from onElClick:

```
  onElClick: function(e, t) {

    // The grid's docked HeaderContainer.
    var me = this,
        ownerHeaderCt = me.getOwnerHeaderCt();

    if (ownerHeaderCt && !ownerHeaderCt.ddLock) {
        // Firefox doesn't check the current target in a within check.
        // Therefore we check the target directly and then within (ancestors)
        if (me.triggerEl && (e.target === me.triggerEl.dom || t === me.triggerEl.dom || e.within(me.triggerEl))) {
            ownerHeaderCt.onHeaderTriggerClick(me, e, t);
        // if its not on the left hand edge, sort
        } else if (e.getKey() || (!me.isOnLeftEdge(e) && !me.isOnRightEdge(e))) {
            me.toggleSortState();
            ownerHeaderCt.onHeaderClick(me, e, t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in every case, parameter `header` is `null`.

see [Ext.grid.feature.Grouping](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping).

Comment: in my case when i check the header element, it is not null but the menu.down('#groupMenuItem') is null. However, how do i find where is this being used in my form as this code is geneated by extjs. this is the value from header element: constructor {xtype: "gridcolumn", stateId: "SurnameState", stateful: true, width: 125, dataIndex: "Surname", …}

Comment: @Baahubali see the "Example" and "Live Preview" at the documentation link; there is far less code required to accomplish this (assuming the store properly handles the grouping; eg. with `GROUP BY` on the server-side).

Comment: Thank you Martin. by adding this statement, the menu starts working: enableGroupingMenu: false. However, i still do not know why is this error happening. Do you think this is an issue on the store side not handling the grouping?

Comment: @Baahubali it is unclear what store it even is; that grid-plugin should be `features: [{ftype: 'grouping'}]` ...here's another [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1pk0) with group-sort; a `memory` store should just support it; an `ajax` store should group server-side, since grouping/sorting parameters are appended to the request URL.

Comment: it is an ajax store. i have two other grid panels with exactly the same scenario and they all work fine. this one works fine only if i refresh the page after the first load (if this tab is not the first one to load) or i make this tab to load first which causes the issue to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems probably a css issue, might be caused by the order in which components load and height applied to header.
Use below css:

```
.ui-grid-header-cell{
height:60px;
max-height:60px;
}
```

Identify the id of header component and use it in place of **.ui-grid-header-cell**